# Empty output when populating 2D range with array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I am trying to populate a 2D range with a 2D array.

At the moment I have this:

```
Sub populate()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim Rows(2) As Variant

Rows(0) = [{1, 2, 3}]
Rows(1) = [{4, 5, 6}]
Rows(2) = [{7, 8, 9}]

With ws
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 3)).Value = Rows
End With


End Sub
```

**I do not get any errors ect., but the *range remains empty* after running the macro.**

The weirdest thing is that I get the correct output when I go like:

```
With ws
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 3)).Value = Application.Transpose(Application.transpose(Rows))
End With
```

I went through numerous articles and Microsoft Documents, but nothing came up to fix my problem.

Comment: `Rows()` is a 1-D array, whose elements are 1-D arrays. You need to get a genuine 2-D array

Comment: Hello, @JohnColeman, Would you post a suggestion of a workaround?
I am trying `Rows1(0, 0) = [{1, 2, 3}]
Rows1(0, 1) = [{4, 5, 6}]
Rows1(0, 2) = [{7, 8, 9}] `, but it throws an error.

Comment: Declare `Dim Rows(2, 0) As Variant`

Comment: You already have a working option so it's not really clear to me what you're looking for? You could simply create a 2D array to start with: `Dim Rows() As Variant: Rows() = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]`

Comment: Good one @Rory! How can this work with Rows() being array of arrays? eg. `Rows = [{Rows1, Rows2, Rows3}]`  Where `Rows1, Rows2, Rows3` are 2D arrays?

Comment: If you want to use `Evaluate` then maybe try: `Rows(0,0) = [Row(1:3)]`, `Rows(1,0) = [Row(4:6)]` and `Rows(2,0) = [Row(7:9)]`. Is that what you are trying to do? Check the locale variables window to see what all different options do to your arrays.

Comment: OK. Let's put it this way...
`Rows1 = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]
Rows2 = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]
Rows3 = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]`
`Rows = [{Rows1, Rows2, Rows3}]`

Comment: Yes, as per my other comments and @Rory his one; `Dim Rows(2,0) as Variant` > `Rows(0, 0) = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]`, `Rows(1, 0) = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]` and `Rows(2, 0) = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]`. Check the locale variables window. Would that be it?

Comment: Now I see. Thank You.

Comment: Last thing @JvdV... I need to add values to the elements. I need to add 1 to element `1` of the first array of `Rows(0,0)` (`Rows(0, 0) = [{`**1**`, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}] `). How do I access it?

Comment: Also, I have the same problem again - The output is empty

Comment: With the last comment of mine you can add a value through `Rows(0, 0)(1, 1) = "Your value"`, this will change the value of the first element of the first 2D array in the first element of your 2D array =).......ehh, yes correct haha

Comment: @JvdV, I got that from the Watch Window and added it to the code. It adds the value to the element, but the output to the range remains empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203031/discussion-between-i--newb-and-jvdv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not following why you are interested in a 2D-array within a 2D-array, but (also as per @Rory his comment, you can try the following:

```
Sub populate()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad1")

Dim Rows(2, 0) As Variant

Rows(0, 0) = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]
Rows(1, 0) = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]
Rows(2, 0) = [{1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9}]

'Rows(0,0)(1,1) = "value" 'If you want to change. This example will change the first element of the 2D-array within the first element of your first 2D-array.

With ws
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 3)).Value = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Rows(0, 0))) 'Will transpose your first element in your initial 2D-array (not sure if this is put correctly in English)
End With

End Sub
```

---

You can implement a `For x = Lbound(rows) to Ubound(rows)` if you want to do the above operation for each element in your 2D-array.

In chat it becomes clear OP also wants to implement the following:

```
reasonArr(1, 0) = [{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}]
```

Which threw an error. This is because the provided line to `Evaluate` exceeds 255 characters.

Comment: Thank you, but I've got this already. Let's continue in chat.